# How to create this year_month sales and previous year_month sales in two different columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, lookup, data-wrangling

I need to create two different columns, one for this year sales and one column for last year sales from a transactional level data?

Data format:-

```
Date                | bill amount
```

1. 2019-07-22    |    500
2. 2019-07-25    |    200
3. 2020-11-15    |    100
4. 2020-11-06    |    900
5. 2020-12-09    |    50
6. 2020-12-21    |    600

Required format:-

Year_month    |This month Sales | Prev month sales

1. 2019_07    |        700            | -
2. 2020_11    |        1000          | -
3. 2020_12    |        650            | 1000

Answer (score 0):

The relatively tricky bit is to figure out what the previous month is. We do it by figuring out the beginning of the month for each date and then rolling back by 1 month. Note that this will take care of January -> December of previous year issues

We start by creating a sample dataframe and importing some useful modules

```
from io import StringIO
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
data = StringIO(
"""
date|amount
2019-07-22|500
2019-07-25|200
2020-11-15|100
2020-11-06|900
2020-12-09|50
2020-12-21|600
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data,sep='|')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df
```

we get

```
    date        amount
0   2019-07-22  500
1   2019-07-25  200
2   2020-11-15  100
3   2020-11-06  900
4   2020-12-09  50
5   2020-12-21  600
```

Then we figure out the month start and the previous month start using datetime utilities

```
df['month_start'] = df['date'].apply(lambda d:datetime(year = d.year, month = d.month, day = 1))
df['prev_month_start'] = df['month_start'].apply(lambda d:d+relativedelta(months = -1))
```

Then we summarize monthly sales using `groupby` on month start

```
ms_df = df.drop(columns = 'date').groupby('month_start').agg({'prev_month_start':'first','amount':sum}).reset_index()
ms_df
```

so we get

```
    month_start prev_month_start    amount
0   2019-07-01  2019-06-01          700
1   2020-11-01  2020-10-01          1000
2   2020-12-01  2020-11-01          650
```

Then we join (merge) `ms_df` on itself by mapping 'prev_month_start' to 'month_start'

```
ms_df2 = ms_df.merge(ms_df, left_on='prev_month_start', right_on='month_start', how = 'left', suffixes = ('','_prev'))
```

We are more or less there but now make it pretty by getting rid of superfluous columns, adding labels, etc

```
ms_df2['label'] = ms_df2['month_start'].dt.strftime('%Y_%m')
ms_df2 = ms_df2.drop(columns = ['month_start','prev_month_start','month_start_prev','prev_month_start_prev'])
columns = ['label','amount','amount_prev']
ms_df2 = ms_df2[columns]
```

and we get

```
|    |   label |   amount |   amount_prev |
|---:|--------:|---------:|--------------:|
|  0 | 2019_07 |      700 |           nan |
|  1 | 2020_11 |     1000 |           nan |
|  2 | 2020_12 |      650 |          1000 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @piterbarg's data, we can use resample, combined with shift and concat to get your desired data:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(
    """
date|amount
2019-07-22|500
2019-07-25|200
2020-11-15|100
2020-11-06|900
2020-12-09|50
2020-12-21|600
"""
)
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="|", parse_dates=["date"])
df

        date    amount
0   2019-07-22  500
1   2019-07-25  200
2   2020-11-15  100
3   2020-11-06  900
4   2020-12-09  50
5   2020-12-21  600
```

Get the sum for current sales:

```
data = df.resample(on="date", rule="1M").amount.sum().rename("This_month")
data

date
2019-07-31     700
2019-08-31       0
2019-09-30       0
2019-10-31       0
2019-11-30       0
2019-12-31       0
2020-01-31       0
2020-02-29       0
2020-03-31       0
2020-04-30       0
2020-05-31       0
2020-06-30       0
2020-07-31       0
2020-08-31       0
2020-09-30       0
2020-10-31       0
2020-11-30    1000
2020-12-31     650
Freq: M, Name: This_month, dtype: int64
```

Now, we can shift the month to get values for previous month, and drop rows that have 0 as total sales to get your final output:

```
(pd.concat([data, data.shift().rename("previous_month")], axis=1)
 .query("This_month!=0")
 .fillna(0))

          This_month    previous_month
date        
2019-07-31  700         0.0
2020-11-30  1000        0.0
2020-12-31  650         1000.0
```